# How to create an Edge extrusion?

Tags: modeling

Is there an easy and efficient way to create an edge extrusion in a hard surface like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you considered a loop cut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like keeping things procedural, and as much non-destructive as possible.

If you strive for the same goals, then you can use these techniques.

Draw a curve or mesh object in the shape of the cuts you want to make, select it, then Shift-Select the mesh object and enter *Edit Mode*.

Under *Edit Mode* select all faces and use the *Knife Project* modifier to cut the shape into the object.

[image: Knife Project]

Now in your mesh mark all edges you want to use as "edge extrusions" as sharp. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Mark Sharp* including the ones you cut and any other you may want.

Then just use a combination of *Edge Split* modifier > *Solifdify* modifier > *Bevel* modifier, and you have an easy to edit object with only the desired edges with indents.

[image: Modifiers]