# Cut a solid along an edge

Tags: modeling

If I have this cylinder,

[image]

How can I cut it along the edge passing through?

(another question: is necessary that edge I created to prepare the cut?)

Comment: No, you don't need that edge, in fact it is best of you remove it. I'd advise using the *Knife Project* operator, you'll need another "cutting" object. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63719/cut-out-surplus-material/63721#63721 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/50560#50560 also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67933/how-to-create-an-edge-extrusion/67944#67944

Comment: maybe simply use the knife tool available in edit mode, there you don't need an extra object... Just hit `K` and click on the vertices composing the edge

Comment: True, forgot about that one

Comment: Edit mode Boolean is a good option for what you want to do.  You just need some clean up after doing the Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Bisect tool.

Click Numpad 5 to enter into Orthographic View, then click Numpad 7 to go to top view.

Click A to select everything, then click Spacebar and type Bisect.

Click and drag across the cylinder while it is selected. This will cut a line into it along where you clicked.

Next, on the left tab, under bisect, make sure Fill and Clear Inner (or Clear Outer) are checked, or uncheck them if you simply want to add the edges along the mesh.

[image]